# ReadOnly JMS message

Tags: java, jms

Can somebody tell me Why the body and properties of a `javax.jms.Message` are made read-only after delivery in `JMS` spec. Is there any valid reason behind this. Thanks.

I will change the question a bit by reading [Peter Lawrey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16820865/readonly-jms-message/16820941?noredirect=1#16820941) comment. While i was reading one [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596522045) it was mentioned as below:

```
> Why are both the body and properties made read-only after delivery? It
> allows the JMS provider more flexibility in implementing the Message
> object. For example, a JMS provider may choose to stream a
> BytesMessage or StreamMessage as it is read, rather than all at once.
> Another vendor may choose to keep properties or body data in an
> internal buffer so that it can be read directly without the need to
> make a copy, which is especially useful with multiple consumers on the
> same client.
```

here i couldn't understand the last line which says:

> which is especially useful with multiple consumers on the same client

what does that means. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you think of a valid reason to change it?

Answer (score 1):

Received messages cannot be altered as this would imply other receivers of the message may or may not see those changes.  It is assumed that changing a received message is more likely to be a mistake than useful.

Comment: take an example pub-sub. A copy of the message will be send to the consumers by the JMS provider. Then one consumer want to change the message (of its own copy) and send it back as new message. In this case it's immaterial whether the other consumers see these changes or not. so is there any other valid reason for read only message type.

Comment: Why wouldn't you create a new message with the contents of the original message?  You have to change the destination, unique ids and a number of other details any way so you are not saving much by resending a message.

Comment: @PeterLawrey What are the benefits of having clearBody and clearProperties methods if it is not useful to modify the message content?